# What is the easiest way to access a small amount of mobile data in Europe?

Tags: europe, cellphones, uber

I have booked a future Über ride from Zürich Station to the Airport. My issue is that I don’t have a travel SIM, or by extension mobile data. What should I do so as to know if a ride has been accepted, and when the driver will arrive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s free WiFi in the station. https://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/railway-stations/products/free-wifi.html

Comment: Well if you’re concerned about security, you pay for it. So by a mobile sim and pay for data!

Comment: @ThE iLIEgAl aLiEn You should add that comment to your answer - the small saving on not buying a mobile SIM or getting a temporary add-on to existing SIM isn’t worth the security risk of using an open WiFi network IMHO

Comment: @Traveller Why wouldn't you use your VPN, as you would in a coffee shop or any other place like that?

Comment: @Traveller Perhaps because in the last two decades of using free WiFi everywhere I go I’ve not suffered any security exploitation (at least that I am aware of), I am not the most security conscious. I never met free WiFi that I didn’t jump on.